# Is there any way to stop background output from breaking up input in a Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, io, tail

Running a Linux terminal, I have a long-running `tail` background process which produces terminal output from time to time to notify me of log changes.  Since it's in the background, I want to be able to run it and continue working on the terminal.  However, whenever `tail` outputs while I'm typing, the output inserts itself after whatever text I'd already typed on that line, and I have to abandon the line and start over.  For instance, typing `abcdefghijklmnop`, with a `tail` message of `Log Updated!` gives:

```
user@server:~$ abcdefghijklmLog Updated!               
nop
-bash: abcdefghijklmnop: command not found
```

Is there any way to pipe the `tail` output to print while still preserving my half-written input lines?  Bash does somehow distinguish between what I typed and what `tail` output, so there is an input buffer of some kind that's preserved - is there a way to have `tail` erase the characters which have been written, print, and then print those characters to the standard input?

Comment: Run it in a separate terminal(window) ?

Comment: Definitely possible, but then the notifications aren't as useful or immediate unless I add "\a" via `sed` to make an audio prompt, which isn't always desirable.  Wouldn't be the end of the world to just use another terminal, of course, but I figured I'd ask regardless.

Comment: @HiggstonRainbird what is the reason why you don't use system's notifications, e.g. those of your window manager, rather than polluting the terminal? In Gnome 3 for example, they would even stick in the lower-right hand corner, so you can't possibly miss them even if you go take a break.

Comment: Can you use emacs? Its shell mode will handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tail` won't do what you are asking, but the hint about `sed` is useful.  If you run in [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), and the `tail` process is running in another window (and piping through `sed` to append a `\a` ASCII BEL to the end of each line), `screen` [will notify you in its status line](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Bell) when the BEL is seen on the other window.

I use this in some build-scripts, to remind me when the (partly interactive) task is done.

A Window manager is less useful for this sort of thing if your connection to the machine doing the work is via `ssh`, no GUI.

Comment: This is exactly what I need - I am connected via `ssh`, and this will let me monitor it without interfering with my input lines.  I may actually use the split-screen functionality instead of just the notifications, but either way, `screen` or `tmux` will work.